# skip records based on columns condition

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have a question in sql server

table name : Emp

```
Id  |Pid  |Firstname| LastName  | Level
1   |101  | Ram     |Kumar      | 3
1   |100  | Ravi    |Kumar      | 2
2   |101  | Jaid    |Balu       | 10
1   |100  | Hari    | Babu      | 5
1   |103  | nani    | Jai       |44
1   |103  | Nani    | Balu      |10
3   |103  |bani     |lalu       |20
```

Here need to retrieve unique records based on id and Pid columns and records which have duplicate  records need to skip.

Finally I want output like below

```
Id  |Pid  |Firstname| LastName  | Level
1   |101  | Ram     |Kumar      | 3
2   |101  | Jaid    |Balu       | 10
3   |103  |bani     |lalu       |20
```

I found duplicate records based on below query

```
select id,pid,count(*) from emp group by id,pid having count(*) >=2
```

this query get duplicated records 2 that records need to skip to retrieve output

please tell me how to write query to achieve this task in sql server.

Comment: please only tag the appropriate sql version. tagging all version doesn't help

Comment: Hi Here We need to consider  unique records based on id + pid if this combination not have unique then skip related all duplicated records.

Answer (score 2):

Since your output is based on unique `ID` and `PID` which do not have any duplicate value, You can use `COUNT` with partition to achieve your desired result.

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c36ac/2)**

**Sample Data**

```
CREATE TABLE Emp
    ([Id] int, [Pid] int, [Firstname] varchar(4), [LastName] varchar(5), [Level] int);

INSERT INTO Emp
    ([Id], [Pid], [Firstname], [LastName], [Level])
VALUES
    (1, 101, 'Ram', 'Kumar', 3),
    (1, 100, 'Ravi', 'Kumar', 2),
    (2, 101, 'Jaid', 'Balu', 10),
    (1, 100, 'Hari', 'Babu', 5),
    (1, 103, 'nani', 'Jai', 44),
    (1, 103, 'Nani', 'Balu', 10),
    (3, 103, 'bani', 'lalu', 20);
```

**Query**

```
SELECT * 
FROM
(
SELECT *,rn = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY ID,PID)
FROM Emp
) Emp
WHERE rn = 1
```

**Output**

```
| Id | Pid | Firstname | LastName | Level |
|----|-----|-----------|----------|-------|
|  1 | 101 |       Ram |    Kumar |     3 |
|  2 | 101 |      Jaid |     Balu |    10 |
|  3 | 103 |      bani |     lalu |    20 |
```

Comment: HI as per give query get result is id Pid Firstname LastName Level rn
1 103 Nani Jai 44 1
2 101 Jaid Balu 10 1
3 103 Bani lalu 20 1  this result not given what I excepted result can you please tell me where we need to change query to get exact result.here need to consider unique records  id +pid  if this combination not have unique then need to skip those related records.

Comment: In your output you have, you only have unique IDs and not combination of ID and PID. for example ID PID 1  100 does not feature in your result. please make sure your result matches your requirement . May be a detailed example of how you select your rows is needed

Comment: mainly need to get unique records based on id + pid. as per you said id pid 1  100 does not feature records that is correct at the same way  id pid 1 103 records also does not feature records in my result but this records came to execute given query.can you please tell me where I done mistake.

Comment: I think, I got your requirement. you need non duplicate combinations of id + pid. i.e. only return id + pid which have count = 1. check updated answer

Comment: @srinivasa - If this answer helped you, please mark it as an [accepted answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).